# SAS datastep to be determined for given scenario

Tags: sas

Need a SAS Datastep for below given scenarios:

Scenario 1:

SAS datastep to identify the list of customers who have not  placed any order.

Scenario 2:

SAS datastep to  get a count of total number of orders placed by each customer in the customer table.

Below is the SAS datastep for Scenario 1 I tried but is there any other way:

```
  `data dummy;
   merge order_newcustomer_table;
   by CustomerID;
   if OrderID=missing;
    run;`
```

For scenario 2 can you suggest some better way?

Tables are as below:

```
CustomerID  CustomerName ContactName Country 
1            Alfred     Maria         Germany 
2         Ana Trujillo  Ana           Mexico 
3          Antonio      Antonio     Mexico 


OrderID     CustomerID           EmployeeID 
1               3                      2 
2               2                      1 
3               2                      3
```

Comment: Your first data step is invalid. Please post sample data for `order_new` and `customer_table` ideally in `datalines` format.

Comment: CustomerID  CustomerName  ContactName  Country 
1           Alfred  Maria          Germany 
2        Ana Trujillo  Ana          Mexico 
3         Antonio    Antonio  Mexico 


OrderID  CustomerID  EmployeeID 
1              3                     2 
2              2                     1 
3              2                     3

Comment: Please edit your question and add this rather than put it in the comments. It is impossible to parse here.

Comment: Hi edited already.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the data sets are sorted by CustomerID before merging.  When merging use the automatic in= flag variable to test if one of the data sets does not have a matching value.

Flag variables have value

- 0=false (no record from data set matches by group value)
- 1=true (there is a record in data set matching by group value)

Example (redone with DOW loop technique):

```
data customers;
  do customerId = 1 to 11;
    output;
  end;
run;

data orders;
  call streaminit(20231114);
  do orderId = 1 to 100;
    customerId = rand('integer', 10);
    amount = rand('integer', 100);
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sort data=customers; by customerId;
proc sort data=orders; by customerId;
run;

data want;
  length customerId 8;
  orderCount = 0;
  totalAmt = 0;
  do until (last.customerId);
    merge customers orders(in=orderFlag);
    by customerid;
    orderCount + orderFlag;
    totalAmt + amount;
  end;
  keep customerId orderCount totalAmt;
run;
```

You will get output the following data set.  No need for multiple data sets.  orderCount = 0 is customer with no orders.

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample for Scenario 2

Comment: What is customerOrderCount?

Comment: Hi it is three @Richard

Comment: Hi The above code is giving me result like all in one table like customer order count customer wise and customer not placed any order it is better to separate that is to create two SAS datasteps scenario wise so that it can give one resultset properly.